# Can I land a plane in a field in the UK and Republic of Ireland?

Tags: landing, regulations, international

So I already saw this question here for the US, but I live in the UK and quite close to the border with the Republic of Ireland (ROI). We have property over the border in the ROI and I was wondering if I could fly back and forth by using the fields to take off and land in a small plane like the SD-1?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you're new to the site you might find the [tour] is helpful. I reworded your question a little to hopefully make it a bit clearer; if I got it wrong then feel free to roll back my changes or edit further yourself.

Comment: Is the question about crossing borders (either generally or that specific one), landing off-airport on your own property, or the specific aircraft named (or experimental craft generally)? If more than one of those, it may be best to ask each piece as a separate question.

Comment: Well you'll need permission from the land owner to land and take off.  Also, there's a planning rule in the UK that says you can use land for only 28 days each year for flying if you don't have specific consent for an airfield

Comment: Well my family owns a some land in ROI so even if the plane was only flying around there for the summer?

Comment: Also @daveGremlin what do you mean “specific consent”?

Comment: @ddoherty958 - sorry, I meant specific planning consent from the local authority.  There's a recent discussion that touches on the subject here: https://forums.flyer.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=107244

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ireland allows ECAC-registered experimental amateur-built aircraft to operate in its airspace for up to 28 days at a time, [as explained here](https://www.iaa.ie/general-aviation/aircraft-categories/amateur-built-aircraft), **as long as your aircraft is legal to fly in the country in which it is registered**. This link also contains information on what to do if you plan to stay longer than that.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that answers it. Up to 28 days for a home built aircraft in the ROI. We are the landowners so no worries there. The summer looks eventful!

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't shuttle back and forth over the border from one field to another between the UK and Republic of Ireland (RoI) because of regulations. The RoI requires you go through an airport of entry when entering and leaving the country, see the IAA [AIP Gen 1.2-1](http://iaip.iaa.ie/iaip/IAIP_Frame_CD.htm):

> Aircraft landing in the territory of Ireland must first land at an
>   International aerodrome or at a licensed aerodrome where customs and
>   immigration facilities are available. Aircraft departing must finally
>   depart from an International Aerodrome or from an aerodrome where
>   customs and immigration facilities are available.

The UK has no requirement to take off and land from a customs airfield, you can go and land from anywhere (from a customs perspective), which is handy. You do have to notify Special Branch at least 12 hours ahead of your flight if you are going to and from the RoI, channel islands or Isle of Man and give them details on who is going and where you are going from and to. You must do this even if you plan to go to and from a customs airport on the UK side.

In the UK you can use a field up to [28 days a year](http://flyinglessons.co.uk/setting-up-your-own-airstrip/) without getting planning permission from the council, provided you own the land (or have permission from the owner) and it is safe to do so. If you plan to do more than 28 days you'd need to talk to the local council and the CAA. I don't know about the RoI though.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Irish customs regulations that you mentioned?

Comment: Sure @Pondlife, see my edit.